# pygradle pivy-importer downloaded python package name does not match

Tags: python, gradle, dependency-management, pypi, grpc

Using pivy-importer downloaded the pypi package to local repo:

```
java -jar pivy-importer-0.3.37-all.jar --repo pygradle-repo grpcio-tools:1.0.1

...
18:58:17.677 INFO  c.l.p.i.deps.DependencyDownloader - Pulling in grpcio-tools:1.0.1
18:58:19.701 INFO  c.l.p.i.deps.DependencyDownloader - Pulling in grpcio:1.0.1 
...
```

Below files are created as a result:

```
myrepo/pypi/grpcio-tools/grpcio-tools-1.0.1.ivy
myrepo/pypi/grpcio-tools/grpcio_tools-1.0.1.tar.gz (Note the underscore)
myrepo/pypi/grpcio/1.0.1/grpcio-1.0.1.ivy
myrepo/pypi/grpcio/1.0.1/grpcio-1.0.1.tar.gz
...
```

Then command

```
./gradlew build
```

results in

```
* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':python'.
> Could not find grpcio-tools.tar.gz (pypi:grpcio-tools:1.0.1).
```

This is what I have in my build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    python 'pypi:grpcio-tools:1.0.1'
    ...
}
```

Am I missing a configuration or misconfiguring?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately we slipped up when we named gRPC's tooling package inconsistently with everything else. If you change the dependency name from `grpcio-tools` to `grpcio_tools`, it'll *probably* work for now. I believe we can have a [fix](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/pull/9180) in by the next minor version update, at which point what you have written *should* work.

n.b. I write this without knowing much about pivy.